# Why many MongoDB connections appear in the cluster if I only connected once?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, database-connection, connection-pooling

I want to understand why so many connections are up in my cluster if I only connected to it once.

This is my mongodbConnection.js file. I wrote it in a way I tought it would connect to the database only once and then reuse that connection later, but in the cluster it shows more than one connection, I just want to know why this happens, is it normal? I'm using NextJS and I know that the serverless functions can potentialy create more than one connection, but this code doesnt prevent this? It clearly returns the already stablished connection if the readyState === 1.

```
let cachedBucket;

async function connectToDatabase(dbname = "") {
  const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI.replace("{dbname}", dbname);

  if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 1) {
    console.log("Already connected");

    if (cachedBucket) {
      return { connection: mongoose.connection, bucket: cachedBucket };
    }

    cachedBucket = new GridFSBucket(mongoose.connection.db, {
      bucketName: "Arquivos",
    });

    return { connection: mongoose.connection, bucket: cachedBucket };
  }

  console.log("Not connected");

  return await mongoose
    .connect(uri, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Connected");
      mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", () => {
        console.log("Mongoose disconnected from MongoDB cluster");
      });
      cachedBucket = new GridFSBucket(mongoose.connection.db, {
        bucketName: "Files",
      });

      return { connection: mongoose.connection, bucket: cachedBucket };
    });
}

export default connectToDatabase;
```

If someone could explain to my if it's normal to happen this amount of connections when calling mongoose.connect only once.

Comment: What value do you mean by "many"?

Comment: It vary, sometimes is 7, then changes to 9, 15, 20. Sometimes it also decreases. I just don't get why more than one connection if I'm just establishing one.

Comment: this behavior depends on a mongo client configuration. You client will have at least a number of opened connection (for your operation) that are specified (if any) in minPoolSize option. Also any "failing" for operation may require creating a new connection.  Then a new operation in some cases may create a new connection instead previously created. ***But***, in addition a number of connection are created for technical reasons in the client background threads.

Comment: So I'm not a node/mongoose developer, but I assume the behavior there is the same as in other drivers and if so, you can't really expect particular number of connection from the client to the server